# How to retrieve on the Product Code and Description of all the products without a supplier. Use proper syntax in retrieving the values

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

How can I retrieve on the Product Code and Description of all the products without a supplier in sql?

[image]

Comment: Post your code and data as text, not images

Answer (score 0):

By using `IS NULL` you can select all the rows that have no/null Supplier.

```
SELECT `ProductCode`, `Description` FROM yourtablename WHERE `supplier` IS NULL;
```

**What is a `NULL` Value?**

> A field with a NULL value is a field with no value.

**How to test for `NULL` values?**

> It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.
> We will have to use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.

Check **[MySQL NULL Values](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_null_values.asp).**